# Shared tooltip position in kendo ui Angular 2 chart

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I would like to change the position of Shared Tooltip. As it is hindering select columns.

I am trying to achieve the result in http://dojo.telerik.com/IJiYI/18 in Kendo UI Angular 2 chart component.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.